# Getting a 404 on refresh with an Angular app deployed on Azure Linux App Service

Tags: angular, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an Angular app that calls a .NET 6 BAckend. I've deployed this on a Linux App Service over at Azure.

I'm using HashLocationStrategy in my Routing Module:

```
 providers: [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}]
```

This however adds a '#' on my url. I would like to remove this. So I have used **PathLocationStrategy**

```
providers: [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy}]
```

This works fine on my local as I can navigate between pages of my web app and hit refresh. All good.

The issue is that when I deployed my web app on Azure Linux Web App. As soon as I navigate away from my home page and hit refresh, I get a "404 Not Found" Error.

I understand that this is because I am using Angular which is a SPA.

Does this have something to do with the Linux Web App Service that I am using? How do I get around this?

I have the below as a startup command on my release pipeline and portal configuration

```
pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot/build --no-daemon --spa
```

A lot of suggestions appear to have a web.config with rewrite rules but I don't think that'll help me as I am using a Linux Web App.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a fallback config file so azure could know where it left off when you refresh your app. take these steps in order to fix the issue

- create file named staticwebapp.config.json inside your project folder or (root folder).
- add this configuration in it.

  ```
       {
         "navigationFallback": {
         "rewrite": "/index.html",
         "exclude": ["/images/*.{png,jpg,gif}", "/css/*"]
          }
       }
  ```

And you can change staticwebapp with your azure deployment plan.
I hope this solves your issue because it worked for me